# Android lint: How to disable "NewerVersionAvailable" check for testCompile dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, lint, android-lint

I'm using `NewerVersionAvailable` lint check to determine newer dependencies versions. But it looks like that this check is useful only for `implementation` dependencies. I think we don't need to update `junit` anytime soon. How to disable this check for separate dependency type? It is boring to add `//noinspection` to each `testImplementation` dependency. Example given:

```
dependencies {

    // should warn
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'

    // shouldn't warn
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: How you added check "NewerVersionAvailable". Please post code

Comment: @SagarTrehan. Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should better disable the check for individual dependencies, simply because then one would still be notified of any further outdated libraries:

```
<issue id="NewerVersionAvailable">
    <ignore regexp="junit:junit*"/>
</issue>
```

With such a pattern: `junit:junit*` one can ignore individual dependencies - and one can ignore whole dependency-groups with such a pattern: `junit:*`.

This still needs to be combined with `//noinspection GradleDependency`, because `lint` and the IDE's code-inspection are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration file for lint inside your project and add this line to it, likes below:

```
<lint>
   ...
   <issue id="NewerVersionAvailable" severity="ignore" />
   ...
</lint>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because it would ignore all the warnings.